# What are the differences between stationary and nonstationary black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, non-equilibrium

I am a bit confused about what are the properties that hold for black holes in general and which ones only hold for stationary black holes. Let me try to explain what I know and hopefully people can correct me if I'm wrong.

- All black holes have event horizons, which are defined as the boundary of the region from which geodesics can't escape. All event horizons are null surfaces.
- The area of event horizons must increase.
- When the area of the horizon is constant, the black hole is stationary.
- A Killing horizon is a null surface whose normal vectors are Killing vectors. Hawking's rigidity theorem says that the event horizon of a stationary black hole is a Killing horizon. Does this mean that for non-stationary black holes the event horizon is NOT a Killing horizon?
- Asymptotically flat spacetimes have Killing vectors at infinity that represent translational symmetry and rotational symmetry. Do nonstationary black hole spacetimes also have such asymptotical symmetries? I think that nonstationary spacetimes shouldn't have a timelike Killing vector at future infinity but I'm not sure.
- Stationary black holes also have a bifurcation surface, which is a spacelike codimension-2 surface where the Killing vectors vanish. Does this hold for nonstationary black holes?
- How does the apparent horizon enter into this discussion?